# Using <ul><li> instead of <select><option> insde the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I want to use `ul->li` instead of standard  `select->option`

Here's the code inside the form to select some values:

```
 <select id="group_4" class="attribute_select" 
     onchange="findCombination();getProductAttribute();" name="group_4">
   <option selected="selected" value="21">Option 1</option>
   <option value="22">Option 2</option>
   <option value="23">Option 3</option>
   <option value="24">Option 4</option>
 </select>
```

I need to change this to  `ul->li` so I would be able to style this list as I want. After clicking submit button the value from select group is sent to other page.

Comment: Unless you use a TON of JavaScript, you WILL lose accessibility. For instance, you have to factor in that some people might want to press Tab to navigate your form, and be able to type the text of an option to select it.

Comment: you may use this: http://codepen.io/tahababa/pen/RNeORG since i tried to make it with simple jquery function

Answer (score 2):

Let me save you a bunch of trouble and coding for behavior you weren't expecting by linking you to this:

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Answer (score 0):

I belive that you can't do that without some programming. Try to use this super jQuery plugin insted.

[Chosen jQuery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)